# Android FrameAnimation Issue

Tags: android, animation

I am using `FasterAnimationsContainer` for my frame animation in the android app but the problem is that it disappears when the activity is  resumed. I found that this is a bug in FasterAnimationsContainer. Is there any solution or alternative I can use? I tried `AnimationDrawable` but it is giving a OOM exception.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is it an issue in Android 6.0? I've reported an issue few days ago, because of a change in AnimationDrawable that broke the oneshot animation.
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3122

A workaround for me is to place the last frame as a 1st frame (with duration to 0). So because of the bug, the 1st is displayed on resume, which is the desired end state of the animation.